# При отправке запроса через аякс скрипт бесконечно показывает лоадер

Tags: jquery, ajax

При отправке запроса через аякс скрипт бесконечно показывает лоадер.

Отправляю запрос таким кодом.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'components/my/core.php',
    data: formNm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        // Вывод текста результата отправки
        $(idusersendmessage).html(data);
        $("#content_"+formID).css('display', 'block');
        $('#loader_' + formID).html("");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
        $(idusersendmessage).html(data);
        $("#content_"+formID).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

В самом файле core.php идет обращение по API к другому сайту. Этих запросов много, бывает что на обработку нужно 5 минут. Сами запросы по API выполняются вот только аякс уже ничего не возвращает, так и крутить лоадер. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Пять минут? Какая-то гниль в датском королевстве.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'components/my/core.php',
    data: formNm.serialize(),
    timeout: 0,
    success: function (data) {
        // Вывод текста результата отправки
        $(idusersendmessage).html(data);
        $("#content_"+formID).css('display', 'block');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
        // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
        //$(idusersendmessage).html(data);
        $("#content_"+formID).css('display', 'block');
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('#loader_' + formID).html("");
    }
});
```